# No sound from internal speakers, headphones working, Kubuntu 18.0.4 and Mint 18.3

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio

I know there's plenty of this questions but i've tried almost everything in top google search but nothing worked.
I was using Linux Mint and suddenly sound stop working, only for speakers, headphones are still working. I installed Kubuntu but the problem persists. I leave some information that may help. Some information it's in Spanish but i hope it can be understood.

```
$ inxi -A
Audio: Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-29-generic

pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ha fallado pa_pid_file_create().
```

I also found this in `journalctl`:

```
pulseaudio  [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you have already tried?

Comment: I’ve tried killing and restarting pulseaudio, deleting /var/.config/pulse files, pavucontrol, alsamixer, reinstalling pulse, checking if user was in audio group

Comment: Check if the intel driver is blacklisted by modprobe check $PATH /etc/modprobe.d/sound-blacklist.conf , /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Comment: The snd_hda_intel driver is not blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the problem installing ofono

```
sudo apt-get install ofono
```

If I stop ofono with `systectl`, sound keeps working, so don't know really what happened.

From `apt show ofono`:

```
Homepage: http://www.ofono.org/
Description: Mobile telephony stack (daemon)
 oFono is a stack for mobile telephony devices on Linux.  oFono supports
 speaking to telephony devices through specific drivers, or with generic
 AT commands.
```